# How do I find if rabbitmq delivered a particular message to consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I have done RabbitMQ queue ccing to find out whether there are messages published to queues. How do I find if all of them are delivered to consumers.

Comment: Unless you implement some sort of RPC then there's no way to know.

Comment: You mean write something in erlang. Can you explain how to do that.

Comment: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: It is not clear what this question is asking. If a message is not in the queue, that means it has been delivered.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is not altogether clear, let me address the issue of how (or whether) to know if a particular message (let's call it *message x*) was delivered to a consumer.

First, some theory.

- Message queuing is commonly used across networks - and networks can be unreliable. Further, the machines operating the message system may be unreliable.
- Message queues are usually designated for the processing of a particular type of message. The processing of the message itself may be unreliable.
- As a result of the foregoing, messages have the possibility to be processed/consumed zero or more times (i.e. a message can be dropped, processed once, or processed more than once).

Now, RabbitMQ contains some features that attempt to mitigate the possible failure modes (primary using acknowledgments), but no mitigation technique can be 100% reliable. Therefore, while the reliability is higher, it cannot be guaranteed - and your application needs to be able to cope with the occasional possibility of failure.

There is an inherent assumption in the question that the original **publisher** of *message x* cares about the **consumer** of *message x*.  This indicates that a two-way exchange (e.g. RPC) is needed - one from publisher to consumer for *message x*, then from consumer back to original publisher (*message y*). The original publisher maintains state while the consumer processes *message x*, and the receipt of the *message y* response closes out the state machine.

If the intent is to simply publish a stream of messages, the publisher should neither be aware of the consumers nor care whether or not the messages are consumed.  However, from an application monitoring standpoint, you presumably would care.  You (as the systems administrator) could do a few things to see if messages are being consumed:

1. Monitor the RabbitMQ management console to see publish/consume rates, as well as queue length
2. Set up logging and tracing in your application (perhaps dumping logs off to elasticsearch) - then set up a log analyzer to detect abnormal log conditions
3. Set up performance monitoring on the consuming computers - if there is a problem, you will likely see abnormal statistics on variables like processor time and memory use
4. Send an occasional test message, which can be specially configured to put a marker in the logs, and look for that marker.